# Upload multiple files with one single input

Tags: django

Multiple files do not save in admin, only the first saved in admin.

```
 class Image(models.Model):
        imageuploader_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        image = models.FileField(upload_to ='pictsagram/')
        image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=700)
    
def upload(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
                post = Image(image=f)
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
                print(request.user)
                post.save()
                form.save()
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form})

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Image
    fields = ('image_caption', 'image',)

<form action="{% url 'site:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{%csrf_token%}
<input type="file" name="file" multiple onchange="loadFile(event)" required="" id="id_file">
<button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Remove the `return redirect('/')` out of the `for f in request.FILES.getlist('image'):` loop. You're redirecting before saving the rest of the files.

Comment: @Ben I did as you said, when I upload two files only the last file is saved. I want the both file to be save and display in my database

Comment: You may need to move the `form.save()` line out of the for loop as well (but keep `form.save()` in the `if form.is_valid()` section.

Comment: @Ben I have done that and still yet it saves only one file.

Comment: I have still not solved this, anyone can?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form is for an Image object, but you're trying to create multiple images from a single form submit.

You are creating the Image(), but it doesn't look like you're attaching it to the form. So you'll probably need to reorganize the view something like:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        for image_file in request.FILES.getlist('image'):
            form = PostForm(request.POST, image_file)
            if form.is_valid():
                image = form.save(commit=False)
                image.imageuploader_profile = request.user
                image.save()
                form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form})
```

Also, cut/paste can mess up formatting, but always double-check your indentation for intended flow.

Comment: thank you, i understand your code and it saves only a single image. this is what i want to implement and i find it difficult. see link https://codepen.io/runamuk0/pen/GgPQyQ

Answer (score 0):

use this code:-----------------------------

```
 def upload(request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                    post = Image(image=f)
                    post = form.save(commit=False)
                    post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
                    print(request.user)
                    post.save()
                    form.save()
            return redirect('/')
            else:
                form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {"form": form})

    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image_caption', 'image',)

    <form action="{% url 'site:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple onchange="loadFile(event)" required="" id="id_file">
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
```