# Upload multiple images at once django

Tags: django

How can I submit 3 images at once with a single input.

```
class Image(models.Model):
imageuploader_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.FileField(upload_to ='pictsagram/')
```

Comment: you can check this [link](https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload)

Comment: Hi Hi3e - a very complex answer, maybe think about this from the perspective of a Django field that can upload n number of images...

Comment: @Wind can you make it clear to me, you can assist with a code?

Comment: @Hi3e I think Houzayfa has hit the nail on the head, definitely seems like the best thing to do is use the https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload package...do you need help with this?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by single input?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is too complicated. You just need a form with a file input having the multiple attribute and then save all the files in your view.

E.g. a very basic example

```
#forms.py

class ImageForm(forms.Form):

    images = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

Your html form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And then create your images in your view, using `getlist` on the field

```
    # views.py
    def images_upload(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                for img in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
                    Image.objects.create(imageuploader_profile=request.user, image=img)
                return redirect('images_upload')

        form = ImageForm()

        context = {'form': form}

        return render(request, 'images.html', context)
```

Comment: @Wind this only save one image in database. Is there anyway i can upload 3 images at once and save them all in database?

Comment: No, it will save multiple images in your database. In your html form the "multiple" attribute in the file selector allows you to select multiple files. When you post that form, in the view you loop over each file you selected in your html and create an ```Image``` object for each file. So you can upload as many files as you like with the code I posted with on submit of the form

Comment: this is getting more confusing to me. I have a form with multiple, i can select multiple images but these images is not saved in my database. When i select 2 images, only 1 image is save in database instead of the 2 images. And only one image display on template. Explain with code

Comment: @Hi3e Sorry, I think there is some confusion in the comments. I thought you were addressing me with you comment to this answer, overlooking it was addressed at something else. The code for my comment is in this answer. If it does not work please post your code for the view. My answer works, at least on my computer.

Comment: i used same views as you have posted here, but the problem is that only one image can be uploaded and be shown in the database with the form on template. I am creating a dating website where a user can upload three images at once, not one by one.

Comment: Could you please add ```print(request.FILES)``` after the line with ```if form.is_valid()``` in the view and post the output printed in your console after trying to upload 2 images?

Comment: Or did I misunderstand you: Do you want to have 3 individual file inputs in your html form?

Comment: I use multiple in my form, i selected two images 08.jpg and 02.jpg but only one is saved in database. this is what is printed {'image':[<InMemoryUploadedFile: 02.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}.

Comment: i do not want to have 3 individual file inputs in html form, i just want to have just one file input to upload 3 images at ones when selected.

Comment: this is what i mean https://codepen.io/runamuk0/pen/GgPQyQ can django do this?

Comment: I see. What you want to do is allow uses to pick one image at a time, store the information somwhere on your page and then, if the user has finished, he can submit all images in one go. This is something totally different. Yes, it can be done with django. Please post your current html code including any javascript stuff you are using

Comment: this is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104901/upload-multiple-files-with-one-single-input

Comment: But that is almost the same question. Why did you post i twice? Please try to bring everything together in one question with all relevant information (e.g. the codepen) link. BTW: The ```upload(request)``` code is not the same as the code I posted. Your code is incorrect.

Comment: yes you are right, i changed the code to yours, have you found a way to solve this issue? please post the the code.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this is an instance of where you need to make use of the `ManyToMany` relationship field, creating a new `model` instance which stores one image, e.g., (and this is a simplistic version of something like what you would need).

```
from django.db import models

class ImageAttachment(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to ='pictsagram/')
```

Then, in your Image model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(ImageAttachment)
```

The user will then pass up X number of images to the server, at which point you will create multiple images, and append them to the images field for the `Image` model.

As code organisation goes, I would also consider renaming you `Image` model, as it is actually storing multiple images ...

Comment: Thanks, can you help me with the views, i have been stuck with this for days now.

Comment: I am able to - although I only really work with DRF now, are you using forms and templates?

Comment: i use forms and templates, i will be glad if you can do this for me.

Comment: I followed the link Django Multiupload, when i add form in template {{ form }} it display render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'. i do not know how to get through this.

Comment: I Will take a look today. Could you add as much as you have done already to get me going.